# Anisotropic invariant expansion

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, tensor, tensor-decomposition

I am trying to calculate the second and third invariants for a turbulent flow. I have the second order statistics (both transient and averaged). i.e $uu$, $vv$, $ww$, $uv$, $vw$ and $uw$. These are supposed to be expanded as

$$II = b_{ij} / 2 \, ,$$

and

$$III = b_{ij} b_{jk} b_{ki}/3 \, ,$$

but I am stuck at this point on how to expand them further to get the second and third invariants.

Comment: Should the second invariant be also a scalar?

Answer (score 2):

Besides fixing the second invariant, you need to know that repeated indicies imply summation. So $A_{ii}=\sum_{k=1}^d [A]_{kk}$. This is known as the [Einstein Summation Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). Each of the second-order statistics is a rank 3 tensor that you can sum up at each point of your domain using this convention in order to compute the invariants at those locations.